# Add attribute title to header in grid.GetHtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a grid in MVC like this:

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("WorkHours", header: "C.H. ↑↓",style: "text-align-center"),
        grid.Column("BasicWage", "Vc.Base ↑↓", style: "text-align-center", format: (item) => item.BasicWage.ToString() + " €"),
        grid.Column("WageComplement", "Cmpl. ↑↓", style: "text-align-center"),
        grid.Column("SubsMeal", "Sub.Ref. ↑↓", style: "text-align-center"),
        grid.Column("WageVariableIndex", "Rem.Var.Ind. ↑↓", style: "text-align-center"),
        grid.Column("WageVariableNonAdjustable", "Rem.Var. Ñ Reg. ↑↓", style: "text-align-center"),htmlAttributes: new { @class="compSalTable"})
```

Now I would like to add titles to my headers so when you mouse over it displays a text.

In html code you do it like this:

```
<table>
    <th title="Work Hours"> C.H. ↑↓ </th>
    ....
</table>
```

How to do it in MVC grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in way to do it.  You can see from the [signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid.column%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) that `WebGrid.Column` only accounts a string for the header (there's no way to specify HTML attributes).

What you might have to do use use a Javascript hack.  For example:

```
// hopefully you can render this lookup part using a Razor loop
var titleLookup = {
    "C.H. ↑↓", "Work Hours",
    "Vc.Base ↑↓", "Basic Wage",
    ...
};

$("table th").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("title", titleLookup[$(this).text().trim()));
});
```

This is the problem you often run into with any RAD-type thing like WebGrid.  Soon you hit a point where you need a feature that isn't supported, and it becomes very tedious to implement basic things.

Comment: @user3384203 I think the problem with my original answer was that `el` is not JQuery-wrapped.  Please see my updated answer.